# How do I create a user control with 3 combo boxes and a different data binding for each?

Tags: c#, data-binding, controls, combobox

I've done some extensive searching before finally deciding to ask this question. I've followed the MSDN tutorials on creating User Controls that use Simple, Complex and Lookup Data Binding.

- [Walkthrough: Creating a User Control that Supports Simple Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171926%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a User Control that Supports Complex Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233813%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a User Control that Supports Lookup Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233787%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

And they work great...for a User Control that only uses a single Combobox or Gridview.

Now I want to create a User Control with three different Comboboxes. I want to bind each one to a different Table. The tables are 'Names', 'Types', and 'Products'.

The MSDN tutorials involve creating DataBindingProperties for a single Combobox, but do not show how to do the same for a user control that contains more than one.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace CS
{
    [System.ComponentModel.LookupBindingProperties(
       "DataSource", "DisplayMember", "ValueMember", "LookupMember")]
    public partial class LookupBox : UserControl
    {
        public object DataSource
        {
            get{ return comboBox1.DataSource; }
            set{ comboBox1.DataSource = value; }
        }

        public string DisplayMember
        {
            get{ return comboBox1.DisplayMember; }
            set{ comboBox1.DisplayMember = value; }
        }

        public string ValueMember
        {
            get{ return comboBox1.ValueMember; }
            set{ comboBox1.ValueMember = value; }
        }

        public string LookupMember
        {
            get{ return comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(); }
            set{ comboBox1.SelectedValue = value; }
        }

        public LookupBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as you can see, there is only one Combobox mentioned in the code. I need to have three Comboboxes, each bound to a different table as mentioned above.

Please, I'm banging my head against the wall. I'm not too well versed in User Controls (although I have used them in ASP.NET), but it seems like a good idea make one since I'm going to be using these three Comboboxes together quite a lot in different places in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `UserControl` that contained three of your `LookupBox`'s.  For example:

```
public partial class MyLookupBoxes : UserControl
{
    public LookupBox()
    {
        // Add the 3 LookupBox to this UserControl using the designer
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupDataSources();
    }

    private void SetupDataSources()
    {
        namesLookupBox1.DataSource = names_data_source_1;
        // ...
        typesLookupBox2.DataSource = types_data_srouce_2;
        // ...
        productsLookupBox3.DataSource = products_data_srouce_2;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what I am planning on doing. These three LookupBoxes will be part of a single user control (Called 'Description'), and THAT user control is going to be added to several other user controls. So it is basically a user control, inside another user control, inside another.                          Thank you for your answer. The code you have makes sense to me, but I'm curious as to what the code for the next user control (which will contain this one) looks like. I mean, if I have three nested controls, do I have to dig three levels deep every time?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply extrapolate what you know with what you need:

```
public object DataSource1
{
    get{ return comboBox1.DataSource; }
    set{ comboBox1.DataSource = value; }
}
public object DataSource2
{
    get{ return comboBox2.DataSource; }
    set{ comboBox2.DataSource = value; }
}
public object DataSource3
{
    get{ return comboBox3.DataSource; }
    set{ comboBox3.DataSource = value; }
}
```

Though you probably want to make better descriptive names than ..1, ..2, ..3.